# Create subclass using parent's generic Builder

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, builder

I am exploring using the Builder design pattern to create subclasses of a parent object, based specifically on the generic type of the subclass. That sentence is kind of confusing, here is what I mean:

```
public class Animal(){
    private String name;
    private String gender;

    public Animal(Builder<?> builder){
        this.name = builder.name;
        this.gender = builder.gender;
    }

    public static Builder<T extends Animal>{
        private String name;
        private String gender;

        public Builder<T> setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        } 

        public Builder<T> setGender(String gender){
            this.gender = gender;
            return this;
        }        

        public T build(Class<T> clazz){
            try {
                Constructor<T> c = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(Builder.class);
                c.setAccessible(true);
                return c.newInstance(this);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Except, this ends up being rather error prone and "hackish". I want to be able to have one Builder that creates all the subclasses.

**Question**

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe the Builder design pattern is just not suited for my needs. This works, but doesn't feel right.

NOTE: The true needs of this question are not as trivial as the Animal class example. You could imagine I am trying to build a subclass to a parent class that contains many arguments. Using the builder pattern will make this a much easier instantiation and easier to extend for future subclasses.

The subclassed objects will have their own methods ONLY. No extra fields, only methods strictly defined to their type of subclass.

I.e. a Duck is a subclass of bird and it quacks. An emu is a subclass of bird, but I don't want it to quack, it will only run. But I both want them to have a name and gender.

Comment: Someone had left a comment regarding why I posted this here, rather than in code review. The reason is because this is a genuine StackOverflow question... I did provide code that I have tried, but know it wasn't a clean Java solution.  I wanted someone to help me get a better answer using my example code as a starting point to build on and show me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than the user specifying the Animal class, I would have each Animal subclass have its own Builder which can build that Animal.

That is:

```
public abstract class Animal {
  protected Animal(Builder<?> builder) { ... }

  public abstract static class Builder<T extends Animal> {
    // setters for fields common to all animals go here

    public abstract T build();
  }
}

public final class Dog extends Animal {
  private Dog(Builder builder) {
    super(builder);
  }

  public static final class Builder extends Animal.Builder<Dog> {
    @Override
    public Dog build() {
      return new Dog(this);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is something I have just tried before reading your answer. I like it best so far